# cannot change ticks in subplots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, axes, subplot

I am trying to change the ticks in a subplot: the result is in the image below.

I use the following code:

```
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.scatter(d,d1,c=chi,s=25,edgecolor='')
plt.xticks(tic,lab)
plt.vlines(dm,min(d1),max(d1),color='b')
plt.vlines(dma,min(d1),max(d1),color='b')
plt.hlines(d1ma,min(d),max(d),color='b')
plt.hlines(d1ma,min(d),max(d),color='b')
plt.xlabel("$\delta$")
plt.ylabel('$\delta_1$')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.scatter(d,L,c=chi,s=25,edgecolor='')
plt.xticks(tic,lab)
plt.vlines(dm,min(L),max(L),color='b')
plt.vlines(dma,min(L),max(L),color='b')
plt.hlines(Lm,min(d),max(d),color='b')
plt.hlines(Lma,min(d),max(d),color='b')
plt.xlabel("$\delta^\prime$")
plt.ylabel('L')
plt.colorbar()


plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.scatter(d1,L,c=chi,s=25,edgecolor='')
plt.vlines(d1m,min(L),max(L),color='b')
plt.vlines(d1ma,min(L),max(L),color='b')
plt.hlines(Lm,min(d1),max(d1),color='b')
plt.hlines(Lma,min(d1),max(d1),color='b')
plt.xlabel("$\delta_1$")
plt.ylabel('L')
plt.colorbar()

plt.savefig('cnf_lin.png')
plt.show()
```

to change the ticks in the xaxis I use `xticks(tik,lab)` where `tick` and `lab` are lists containing my new ticks and label, but python (2.7 if it matters) overwrites my labels to the old ones.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example of your code?

Comment: @Ffisegydd This might be a problem: lists `d,L,d1` are read from a long file, `dm,LM,d1m` are the mean values and `dma,Lma,d1ma` are the best fit values. the `chi` is the chi squared

Comment: In which case, can you just make up some values that still replicate the issue? Also you can probably reduce it to just one subplot for simplicity? (This is the *minimum* part of a minimum working example :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem (thanks anyway): `xticks` is a method of subplot (I think), so it has to be called in the following way:

```
a1=plt.subplot(2,2,1)
a1.set_xticks(list)  #list contains the new ticks
....  # the rest of the code
```